# OCIError (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails freeze 1.2.3 to run a rails app. Because the app is on a remote machine, I used ssh tunnel (ssh -l -L) to show the app on my screen. When I ran it, it correctly prompted the login page, after I put in the info, I got this error:
OCIError in ServiceController
Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12154

I have tried the same app on a different machine w/o using freeze (because that machine has rails version 1.2.3 while current one has 2.0.2). Is that where the error comes from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's an Oracle error. It sounds like your database setup is incorrect. Put the error number ORA-12154 in Google and you'll find some useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12154 is a classic.  As Sarah points out its nothing to do with your Rails or Ruby per se.  ORA-12154 is generated when the Oracle Client can't connect to the oracle server.  So most likely your setup is wrong in:

1. Your database.yml, if you can connect using tnsping or sqlplus (Oracle client utils) you probably just need to look at this.
2. Your Oracle networking setup, particularly your tnsnames.ora file (found in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin if I remember correctly).  This may need some extra help from a friendly DBA as the tnsnames.ora syntax has quirks.  Check this link [link text](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12154_tns_resolve_service_name.htm) for more info.

Hope that helps.